# Including shared methods in App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use some methods in all my controllers (Laravel 5.8),

I am putting all those needed functions in `App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php` as every controller extends this class.

Is this a good practice? can it cause any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok. And it's based on your methods. I prefer to use some service class for it and use dependency injection to use it inside needed controllers. It allows to be more flexible and it's easier for testing. But it's up to you. Hope it helps. 
Please see on [service containers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container) and [service providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers).
Actually you can use your class without registration it. Laravel will use mechanism of Reflaction to use needed class in dependency injection. But it's useful to understand how it works. 
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides us with many built-in helper functions that you can call anywhere within your application. They make you workflow convenient for working with arrays & objects, paths, strings, URLs and other types.

Although there are many helper functions defined in the laravel core, you can define your own helper functions in laravel to avoid repeating the same code. It ensures better maintainability of your application.

You can [refer this](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) to write a helper file.

OR you can create a Trait and use it any class.